# GIT : How to move git folder inside subfolder and rewrite history to pretend it always was like that?

Tags: javascript, git, version-control, branch, git-filter-branch

I mistakenly put my .git folder in a higher location than needed :

```
Folder1/
    .git <-- currently here
    myproject/
        .git <--- should be here
```

I'd like to move it inside `myproject` but it would break the backward compatibility when I look to ancien commits from there on...

Is there a way to keep it consistant ? Maybe by rewriting the history / pretending it always was like that ? I guess it could be done with `git filter-branch --tree-filter` but not sure as how ?

Comment: What do you mean "break the backward compatibility"? Did you committed the files outside `myproject` folder bu inside `Folder1` in the git repo?

Comment: You don't need filter-branch per se to do this.  Just move the current contents of the `myproject` folder to the same level as the current `myproject`, and then delete the empty `myproject` folder.  But why do you want to do this?

Comment: If you see 'Making a Subdirectory the New Root' in [rewriting history](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History), it will probably get you started. `git filter-branch` is considered the "nuclear option", so it will take a bit of work to get it to behave perfectly.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT Yes I committed myproject as a whole from Folder1. I am the only one using it tho so I don't care rewriting history. By Breaking history I mean, if I just move .git within myproject and `git status` : everything is considered deleted, and every file in myproject is considered new.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why ? To gain efficiency I guess. It doesn't look weird to you that I have a wrapper folder with only .git in it ?

Comment: Doesn't look strange at all, one of my current projects has this layout.  The critical thing is that all the content which you want to be managed by Git is _within_ the `.git` folder.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. I guess I should not bother doing that plus filter branch seems a little bit too tricky. One easy solution would be the one suggested by @TimBiegeleisen tho.

Comment: Git is fairly lousy at tracking moved/relocated files.  It can break a history and make it hard to track a file past the point where it was renamed or moved, so normally I would try to avoid this unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Makes sense, thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you moved `.git` folder to `myproject` folder, git can not detect the file from it's original relative path, but find files existing in new relative path, so `git status` will report the original files deleted and has new files.

Such as before moving `.git` folder, git track files under `myproject` folder in git repo as `root/myproject/*`. After moving `.git` folder, files under `myproject` folder are under the root of the git repo now (`root/*`). So git detects they are new files (untracked) and thinks the files in `root/myproject/*` no longer exist (deleted).

And since the git repo is only for your own use, you can commit the changes directory. If you want to remove the original commits histories when the `.git` folder was under `Folder1`, you can **use `git rebase -i` to drop some commits**.

If you want to keep commit history for the files under `myproject` folder, you should not move `.git` folder but **move the files and folders under `Folder1` while outside `myproject` folder**.

Comment: Not my downvote, but an explanation would be helpful.